# pygame window taking forever to load

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to pygame and I'm just trying to code chess with it but I'm having trouble with the background taking forever to load I've looked up a lot of tutorials and I think everything is fine, what am I doing that's taking so much time?

```py
import pygame 

pygame.init

#create the screen with 800 pixals width and 600 pixals hieght
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

# Background
background = pygame.image.load("chessboard.png")



running = True
while running:

    #RGB colors
    screen.fill((234,0,0))
    #background image
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You need parens after pygame.init(), or it will not initialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `pygame.init` is no function call. This statement does nothing at all. You have to add parentheses to call `init()`:

```py
pygame.init()
```

Furthermore, you missed to update the display ([`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)) in the main applcation loop:

```py
running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    #RGB colors
    screen.fill((234,0,0))
    #background image
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    # update display
    pygame.display.flip()
```